# change video volume for iOS in cordova

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, html, cordova

How can I change iOS video volume and mute using jQuery in cordova.
I have tried...

```
videoId = document.getElementById("startVideo");
videoId.muted = true;
```

... but it is not working.

Comment: Using jQuery you can easily do it: $("video").prop("volume", 0.5); videoId would be an array, so you might want to try videoId[0].volume

Comment: @AnkitTanna no it is not working I tried in both ways. I did remote debugging also for iOS but nothing changing there. Can you help me advance in cordova.thanks

Comment: Put code in code block.